Why does the countdown return to its base value when I click the button?
I started programming in python recently. My program follows the rules of the game of fortune: the player clicks on the button "demarrer", the rules appear, the player clicks on the button "valider", an image appears and the player gives a price by entering it in the input field and clicks on "valider". If the price is higher, the computer indicates it and vice versa. There is also a 60s countdown. This is where the problem occurs: when I click on "valider", for the first time, the image appears but the countdown does not start. I enter a value and click confirm and the countdown starts. Since I have very little chance of finding the right value right away, I'm trying my luck again. So I enter a new number and the countdown returns to its starting value (60 s), so the time is infinite and regenerates each time I click on "valider". I don't know if I was very clear but if anyone could help me I would be happy to accept. Thanks in advance. Here is my script:
from tkinter import *
import time

# Window --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------

window = Tk()
window.minsize(800, 700)
window.maxsize(800, 700)
window.title("Le juste prix")

img_fond = PhotoImage(file="Juste prix redim.png")
image = Label(window, image=img_fond)
image.place(x=0, y=0)

# Def ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def starting():
    text_1 = Label(window, text="Des objets vont apparaître. Donne un prix le plus proche \n    possible dans le temps imparti. Clique sur valider pour commencer.", font=("Verdana", 15, "italic bold"),
               bg="grey", fg="white")
    text_1.place(x=15, y=100)

def timer(duree):
    while duree >= 0:
        time.sleep(1)
        timer_text["text"] = str(duree)
        window.update()
        if duree == 0:
            text_temps = Label(window, text="Tu n'as plus de temps !", fg="white",     bg="#CA3C66",  font="Verdana 20")
            text_temps.place(x=450, y=300)
        duree -= 1

def game():
    price = 96650
    duration = 3000
    img_1 = PhotoImage(file="x6 redim.png")
    x6 = Label(window, image=img_1)
    x6.place(x=100, y=350)
    x6.image = img_1
    player_reponse = int(champs_de_saisie.get())

    if player_reponse > price:
        less_txt_img1 = Label(window, text="Moins cher !", bg="#CA3C66", fg="#E8AABE" , font=("Verdana", 20,"italic bold"))
        less_txt_img1.place(x=150, y=250)
        less_txt_img1.after(duration, less_txt_img1.destroy)
    if player_reponse < price:
        more_txt_img1 = Label(window, text="Plus cher !", bg="#CA3C66", fg="#E8AABE" , font=("Verdana", 20, "italic bold"))
        more_txt_img1.place(x=150, y=250)
        more_txt_img1.after(duration, more_txt_img1.destroy)
    if player_reponse == price:
        win_txt_img1 = Label(window, text="Bravo tu as trouvé !", bg="#CA3C66", fg="#E8AABE" , font=("Verdana", 20, "italic bold"))
        win_txt_img1.place(x=100, y=250)
    timer(60)


# Widgets --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

champs_de_saisie = Entry(window, width=15, font="Arial 15")
champs_de_saisie.place(x=525, y=450)
text_2 = Label(window, text="€", font="Verdana 15", bg="grey", fg="white")
text_2.place(x=675, y=449)
text_3 = Label(window, text="Ton prix :", font="Verdana 15", bg="grey", fg="white")
text_3.place(x=550, y=400)

timer_text = Label(window, text="", bg="#F4CFDF", fg="#A7001E", width=7, font="Arial 30")
timer_text.place(x=525, y=200)


start_button = Button(window, text="Commencer", bg="#212E53", fg="white", font="Arial 15", width=36, command=starting)
start_button.place(x=0, y=0)

valid_button = Button(window, text="Valider", bg="#7AA95C", fg="#e5e7e6", width=10, font="Arial   15", command=game)
valid_button.place(x=550, y=500)

leave_button = Button(window, text="Quitter", bg="#A7001E", fg="white", font="Arial 15", width=36, command=window.destroy)
leave_button.place(x=400, y=0)

window.mainloop()


Every gtime you click Valider, you run the game function, and the last thing that does is to call timer(6). That gives you only 6 seconds to try another guess. Set a global variable to False when the start function runs. Then when you run game, if the value is False then set the variable to True and timer with the duration set to 60.

So what would that look like in code? timer=false and in def game() timer = true? PS : Sorry mistake on my part I put timer(6) instead of timer(60)

Something like this should do it:
onetime = False
def starting():
    global onetime
    onetime = False
# other parts of this function

def game():
# other parts of game ...

    global onetime
    if onetime == False:
        onetime = True
        timer(60)

# remainder of the program

So you can then call game multiple times without resetting the timer.

There's an = missing in if onetime == False:; better yet, avoid the Boolean literal: if not onetime:

@Friedrich Thank you, and well sportted. I have corrected my answer.
